# Daynamic dropdown in jsp Empty. Which is comes from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have  Dynamic drop down list in JSP. country,state,city. I had code it. but problem arise that drop down values comes from MySQL and values do not displayed.
Three jsp files country.jsp, state.jsp, city.jsp
Referred link  http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Ajax/15250-DropDown-in-ajax+jsp.html 
Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var xmlHttp  
var xmlHttp
function showState(str){
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();


}
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
  xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="state.jsp";
  url +="?count=" +str;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

  function stateChange(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }

  function showCity(str){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="city.jsp";
  url +="?count=" +str;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
  function stateChange1(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }
  </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
  <select name='country' onchange="showState(this.value)">   
        <%
        try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo1","root","root"); 
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from country");


     while(rs.next()){
         %>
         <%out.print("rs.getString('countryname')"); %>
          <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString("countryname")%></option>  
          <%
     }
     %><% 
     }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

    }%>
      </select>  
      <br>  
      <div id='state'>  
      <select name='state' >  
      <option value='-1'></option>  
      </select>  
      </div>  

      <div id='city'>  
      <select name='city' >  
      <option value='-1'></option>  
      </select>  
      </div>
      </body> 
      </html>
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? You are hiding the `ClassNotFoundException`if the jdbc driver is not available. Does your database contain any values in the country table? Is the database up and running? Can you connect to the database. Have you ever viewed the generated HTML? You neither close your `ResultSet`nor the `Statement` nor your `Connection` so it's only a matter of time until you'll run into problems with your page. Maybe it would be a good idea to read a good [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: yes,country table contains values. Database conn is also running. But i can't understand about what u say that "You neither close your ResultSetnor the Statement nor your Connection so it's only a matter of time until you'll run into problems with your page"

Comment: hey thank you its done. My mistake is that i had not mysql connector in library folder. :)

Comment: jDBC resources like Statements must be released otherwise you'll have a resource leak and the Database will refuse further requests.

Comment: Hey please give solution for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743805/multiple-dependent-dropdown-list-in-jsp-in-with-thirds-value-depends-upon-first