# Multiple Dependent Dropdown list in Jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have Three Drop-downs in Jsp. Branch, Semester and Subject and values comes from MySQL. Branch and semester are not dependent to each other. But Subject value should be depends on branch and semester both.
I had done following code.
problem arise that though select the both branch and semester drop-down value, Subject drop-down's value not getting means shows blank drop-down field.

FirstTwoDropdown.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@page import="com.connection.*"%>
<%Connection con;
 ResultSet rs;
 Statement st;


 con = connectiondb.condb();
   %>
   <html>
      <head>  
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
      var xmlHttp
          function showsubject(str){
              if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
              else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
              if (xmlHttp==null){
              alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
              return;
              } 
              var url="subject.jsp";
              url +="?count=" +str;
              xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
              xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
              xmlHttp.send(null);
              }
              function stateChange1(){   
              if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
              document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
              }   
              }
      </script> 
      </head>  
      <body>  
      <select name='branch_name' onchange="showsemester(this.value)">  
       <option value="none">Select</option>  
    <% 
   st = con.createStatement();  
   rs = st.executeQuery("select distinct branch_name from subject_tbl");
  while(rs.next()){
     %>
      <option value="<%=rs.getString("branch_name")%>"><%=rs.getString("branch_name")%></option>  
      <%
 }
     %>
      </select>  
      <br>   
      <select name='semester' >
      <option value="none">Select</option>  
    <% 
st = con.createStatement();  
  rs = st.executeQuery("select distinct semester from subject_tbl");
 while(rs.next()){
     %>
      <option value="<%=rs.getString("semester")%> on"><%=rs.getString("semester")%></option>  
      <%
 }
     %>  
      </select>  

      <select name='subject_name' >  
      <option value=''></option>  
      </select> 
      </body> 
</html>
```

subject.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="com.connection.*"%>
<%
String semester=request.getParameter("semester");
String branch_name=request.getParameter("branch_name");
String buffer="<select name='subject_name'><option value=''>Select</option>"; 
Connection con;
ResultSet rs;
Statement st;
 con = connectiondb.condb();
 try{  
 st = con.createStatement();  
 rs = st.executeQuery("Select subject_name from subject_tbl where semester='"+semester+"' and branch_name='"+branch_name+"' ");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString("subject_name")+"'>"+rs.getString("subject_name")+"</option>";  
   }  
 buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
 response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }
 %>
```

Comment: why you not using servlets for database transaction and for business logic?? everything are mixing up in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

*Just as tip*: Try to separate the  business logic from the JSP files.
There are different options to do this one is to use `Servlets` the other approach is to use [Java Bean Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html).

*Second tip*: Close your resources.

```
// Java 7 Try - with resources syntax 
try (
   Connection con = connectiondb.condb();
   Statement st = con.createStatement();  
) 
{
   try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(...)) 
   {
      // do something with your result set 
   } 
}
```

Your database has only **limited** Resources like *Connections*, *Cursors*, ...

*Third tip*: Use Prepared Statements. Otherwise someone may use [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection) to attack your system.

*For your Problem*: Just a guess

The semester value you'll retrieve from your  `FirstTwoDropdown.jsp` is "*semester-value* on" i.e. you append " on" to the value retrieved from the database.

The other thing is that `FirstTwoDropdown.jsp` uses the javascript function `showsemester` which is not defined within the page - so this will never work. And the `showsubject` function sends a query parameter `count` which is not used on the `subject.jsp`.